# oauth 2 to authenticate users stopped working suddenly in all environments

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

We have application on compute engine that is using oauth2(Using GCP credentials) to authorize users to access application and it was working all fine. Suddenly since last two days we are getting 401 not authorize  message from google authenticator instead of access token.

Have verified that the service account is active and APIs access enabled on GCE.

We tried rotating GCP API credentials but that did not work, even one of the environment was allowing to login again but go broken again in the morning.

Here is the sequence of incidents:

1. User hit url to access web app
2. That redirects to -> google auth page, requesting user to login consent
3. Credential provided user and accepted by google.
4. Instead of providing authentication token google is giving message access denied.

Not sure which logs can give clear picture to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your App is External Facing but is still in test mode (not verified), the token will expire after 7 days ([source](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration))

Comment: It is in production Mode and it was running for more than 25 days